# Using Paramiko to ssh into ftp servers in Python

Tags: python, ssh, ftp, paramiko

I'm using the code below to ssh into the `ftp servers`:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("locate my_file.txt")
print ssh_stdout
```

However, I'm using multiple servers so I replace the `server` argument a lot. On the main `ftp server` I'm trying to connect to, I get this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Whenever I try to use other servers though, I usually get this error:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.S SHException: 
Server 'ftp.server.org' not found in known_hosts
```

Does anyone know of any possible solutions to solve either one or both of these problems?

Comment: oops ... sorry I got busy and didnt get back to you about that yesterday (anyway the answers below are correct)

Comment: Does your ftp servers has SSH Server running? Please check whether they are running and port 22 is not blocked by firewall.

Answer (score 2):

To fix your 2nd error, you can tell Paramiko to auto-add new servers:

```
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
```

Take a look at [the docs](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.set_missing_host_key_policy).

Answer (score 1):

For your second problem, you need to add the following line after `ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()`:

```
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
```

This will allow paramiko to auto-accept unknown keys (and should allow you to SSH into those other servers)